# Programmatically Disable IE8 Proxy C#

Tags: c#, proxy

I need to disable the proxy settings in IE8 preferably without using the registry and using an API.
I have been looking into 'InternetQueryOption' (to query device) and 'InternetSetOption'
I can make the changes using the registry and then refresh the browser using:

```
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0); //INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0); //INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH
```

However I am unable to use the same system to check or set the setting in IE which says if it uses the Proxy server for LAN connections, and any assistance or examples would be great

Comment: It's going to be difficult to whack a program like IE over the head with your requirements when it *does* use the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [some example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385384%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#set_connection).

Comment: Cheers, Everytime I was looking for something like that it kept showing information for IE 4 or so...